# Roles come back as null from Azure Analysis Services database when connecting using AMO in C#

Tags: c#, ssas, roles, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have a tabular Azure Analysis Services database with compatibility level 1400. When I connect and try to retrieve the roles using the AMO package the `Roles` property is always `null`, the same for the `DatabasePermissions` property that is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682251/5209435).

I am using the `Tabular.Server` and `Tabular.Database` objects as recommended in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/install-distribute-and-reference-the-tabular-object-model#choosing-which-namespace-to-use-in-code).

I have based my code off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654105/what-is-the-best-way-to-obtain-the-complete-list-of-permission-of-a-given-user-u) and I am connecting using an administrator account.

Proof that roles are setup on the DB that I am accessing:

[image]

Inspecting the database object:

[image]

Interestingly enough I have two other databases inside the same Azure Analysis Services server and they have the same issue.

My code:

```
using (Server server = new Server())
        {
            string serverDomain = "australiasoutheast.asazure.windows.net";
            string serverName = "redacteddevpilotv1";
            string databaseModel = "PilotV1";
            string serverAddress = $"asazure://{serverDomain}/{serverName}";
            //string token = await GetAccessToken($"https://{serverDomain}");
            //string connectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={serverAddress};Initial Catalog={databaseModel};User ID=;Password={token};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate";
            string connectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={serverAddress};Initial Catalog={databaseModel};User ID=redacted;Password=redacted;Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate";

            var t = server.SupportedCompatibilityLevels;
            var x = server.Roles;

            server.Connect(connectionString);

            t = server.SupportedCompatibilityLevels;
            x = server.Roles;

            Database d = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseModel);
        }
```

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/amo/programming-amo-security-objects) goes into how to add roles not how to retrieve them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that instead of accessing roles through `database.Roles` I need to access them via `database.Model.Roles`. I'm not sure why this is or if it is documented anywhere but I was put onto this fact by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44082659/5209435).

After doing this I now have access to the `ModelRole` objects that I want.